# Push object array inside object array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following object array 
I have an array where I push data inside. I want the third one to be an object as well (`doc3`) and push data from another object (`things`) with `forEach` inside too. What am I doing wrong?

```js
var obj = {
  documents: []
};

function print() {
  obj.documents.push({
    "doc1": "",
    "doc2": "",
    "doc3": []

  });

  things.data.forEach(function(item) {
    obj.documents.doc3.push({
      "id": item.id1,
      "id2": item.id2,
      "id3": ""
    });
  });
  
  alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
}

print();
```

Comment: There's nothing related to JSON here (except the output of `JSON.stringify`). http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: `json.documents` is an array. You have to access the element before accessing doc3

Comment: what is `things`? Provide a [mcve]

Comment: Edited your question to remove all those "JSON" that have nothing to do with JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, when you push an object inside an array ...

```
obj.documents.push({
  "doc1": "",
  "doc2": "",
  "doc3": []
});
```

The object tooks place in the first slot of array which has the index of 0.

So Instead of this ...

```
// This is wrong
json.documents.doc3.push({
  "id": item.id1,
  "id2": item.id2,
  "id3": ""
});
```

You have to specify the array index which your initial object is in (which we know is index 0), therefore you should do as below

```
// This is the right way
json.documents[0].doc3.push({
  "id": item.id1,
  "id2": item.id2,
  "id3": ""
});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I'm not the downvoter, but you could provide a bit more of an explanation for your recommendation?

Comment: Sure @Arin5475 :) I'll put some explanation. Tnx for reminding tho

Answer (score 1):

The documents in json object is also an array because you are pushing an object into it

```
json.documents.push({
         "doc1": "",    
         "doc2": "",
         "doc3":[]
  });
```

If you want this, you can access doc3 by using

```
json.documents[0].doc3
```

Or if you dont want json.documents to be an array, initialize it like this

```
json.documents = {
    "doc1": "",    
    "doc2": "",
    "doc3":[]
};
```